# MODx Revolution Multidomain/Contexts same content

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I have a MODx website. It has 3 different contexts. Each context point to an other domain.

In one context (lets say it is C1), I have a resource (a folder) that has many child resources.

I display the resources with a pdoresources-call (frontend). Everything works fine. It lists/display the resources as it should be. When I click on it, it open as well and show me the content of the resources (The site ist something like a block)

But when I go to an other context (C2) and make the same pdoResources-Call
it lists/display the resources as well. But when I click on the resource nothing happened. It do not open because it is another context.

How can I setup MODx Revolution to have different contexts that all can share content (Resources)

Comment: On your C2 call, are you trying to open a page with the url from C1 or C2?

Comment: You are missing the plugin which intercepts the request and tell MODX which resource to serve.

Answer (score 0):

If you organize your resources in a tree with each domain as its own branch, you should setup a single "Start ID" for each context. That happens in the context settings (via main menu).

The full process is beeing described here: https://black-pixel.net/2014/02/24/multilingual-multidomain-site-modx-cms/

Maybe you have to call the PDO-Tools call uncached. Or to make sure, place the call into a chunk, duplicate it and place the context key into it (to have 3 different calls, one per domain).
`[[$subtree-call-C1]]` for C1 etc...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be pointing you to something like `seconddomain.com/parent/child.html` while it should be pointing to `firstdomain.com/parent/child.html`. If that's the case, you should make sure that each of your contexts has the `site_url` (and related `http_host` and `base_url`) context settings, so that MODX knows to send you to a different domain.